# createContext doesn't accept defaultValue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a context by using `createContext` from the react API:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

export const MovieContext =  createContext();

export const MovieProvider = (props) => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(
    [
      {
        original_title: 'name of movie',
        poster_path: 'path_to_poster',
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  );
  return (
    <MovieContext.Provider value={[movies, setMovies]}>
      {props.children}
    </MovieContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MovieProvider;
```

The `createContext()` function shows this error:

> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) index.d.ts(385, 9): An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.

If I make it a string, and pass a string as value the app builds:

```
export const MovieContext =  createContext('');

<MovieContext.Provider value={''}>
  {props.children}
</MovieContext.Provider>
```

What kind of value do I add as a `createContext()` parameter to make it work with the useState hook? I'm following [this guys tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o%20@21:50) and he does it in JS but I'm building my app in TS so it's a bit more strict.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These are the Typescript types, they are described [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L416). There is a comment in the code why this argument should be required, although the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) doesn't say it is required.

```
function createContext<T>(
    // If you thought this should be optional, see
    // https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24509#issuecomment-382213106
    defaultValue: T,
): Context<T>;
```

In your case will correctly set the default parameter like

```
type IMovie = {
    original_title: string;
    poster_path: string;
    id: number;
};

type IMovieContext = [IMovie[], React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IMovie[]>>];

export const MovieContext = createContext<IMovieContext>([[], () => null]);

export const MovieProvider = props => {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState<IMovie[]>([
        {
            original_title: 'name of movie',
            poster_path: 'path_to_poster',
            id: 1,
        },
    ]);
    return <MovieContext.Provider value={[movies, setMovies]}>{props.children}</MovieContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But I think you misunderstood a little bit. The createContext signature now is a empty array, if I'm correct. But the `<MovieContext.Provider value={[movies, setMovies]}>` is a react Hook, again if I'm correct. So now I'm getting an error in that part. `Type '{ original_title: string; poster_path: string; id: number; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[] | (() => never[])'.`

Comment: @PeterBoomsma Updated answer with types. `<MovieContext.Provider value={[movies, setMovies]}>` - not hook, it is just component with value props. Example `useState` - hook

Comment: Thanks, there´s still some magic going on for me but I can now render data from the context provider in another component which was the goal. I think I'll try to find some content regarding context providers and typescript to get a better grasp of what's happening. Cheers.